# gwt-maven-plugin run tests on wrong address

Tags: maven, gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

When maven starts tests using gwt-maven-plugin, it firing up server, and use wrong ip, in my case

```
Starting http://10.0.14.67:60281/com.something.GwtTest.JUnit/junit-standards.html?gwt.codesvr=10.0.14.67:60278 on browser FF17
```

and get access denied error. I want it to start tests on 127.0.0.1, but dont know how. BUT if i run gwt plugin, not gwt:test but gwt:run it starts on 127.0.0.1 and all works fine!
i have such config in maven plugin

```
<failOnError>true</failOnError>
                    <runTarget>http://127.0.0.1:8080/</runTarget>
                    <hostedWebapp>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-gwt</hostedWebapp>
                    <noServer>true</noServer>

                    <includes>**/*TestSuiteGWT.java</includes>
                    <mode>htmlunit</mode>
```

So how i can make it start tests on same 127.0.0.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tests use [`InetAddress.getLocalHost()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost%28%29)`.getHostAddress()`, so there's no way to change it other than changing the JVM's behavior for `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`.
That behavior of the `JUnitShell` is to allow [remote testing](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideTestingRemoteTesting.html) without reconfiguration (contrary to DevMode which requires `-bindAddress`).

A solution is to create a custom "run style" inheriting `com.google.gwt.junit.RunStyleHtmlUnit` and overriding `getLocalHostName()` to return `127.0.0.1`, and using it through `<mode>name.of.your.CustomRunStyleHtmlUnit</mode>`.